# How to check IsLetter in a word without creating a method

Tags: c#

My assignment is to translate a word into pig latin using VS Studio. One of the requirements is to make sure that the word is all letters, but another requirement states **"No methods needed other than 1 block of code for the convert button"**. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to work without creating a new method.

Here's what I have so far:

```
private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int MAX_LENGTH = 12; //maximum length of characters
    const string SUFFIX = "ay"; //add to end of word
    bool isLetter = false; // check if input is all letters

    string input = englishWordTextBox.Text.Trim(); //get trimmed copy of input
        

    foreach (char letter in input)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(letter))
            isLetter = true;
    }

    if ((input.Length <= MAX_LENGTH) &&
        (input != "") &&
        (isLetter = true))
    {
        string firstLetter = input.Substring(0, 1); // isolate first letter of input
        string restOfWord = input.Substring(1, input.Length - 1); //isolate rest of word

        pigLatinWordLabel.Text = restOfWord + firstLetter + SUFFIX; //display piglatin word
    }
    else
    {
        //error message and clear if invalid
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input");
        englishWordTextBox.Text = "";
        pigLatinWordLabel.Text = "";
    }            
}
```

I'm getting an error telling me that bool isLetter is assigned but its value is never used.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks to a commenter I realized I was using "=" when I should have been using "==". It is working enough to pass the error message when I use only numbers but if I mix letters with numbers it's still running the pig latin. Please advise if there's a simple way around this!

Comment: Hi @nekomancer, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check your `if` statement, `isLetter = true`, it should use `==` double equal sign (equal operator). Thank you.

Comment: FYI, "isLetter is assigned but its value is never used", this is not an error, it is a warning notified by the compiler. It will not stop you from running the program. [For your reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0219).

Answer (score 0):

The isLetter boolean variable is set to true if your input contains ateast 1 letter. So if your word is say 123a123, the isLetter would still be true. Its better to assign the isLetter to true and then assign it to false if there is atleast 1 numeric character. You could break the loop (foreach) as soon as you get the first numeric character.

Answer (score 0):

### ISSUE

The way you check each character in the input string that has to be a letter was incorrect.

```
foreach (char letter in input)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(letter))
        isLetter = true;
}
```

The loop will keep iteration and override the previous compared value.

Sample Input & **Expected** Output:

| Input | Comparison Output |
| --- | --- |
| apple | true |
| apple123 | false |
| 123apple | false |
| 123 | false |

Sample Input & **Actual** Output (based on current logic):

| Input | Comparison Output |
| --- | --- |
| apple | true |
| apple123 | false (Correct result, but wrong logic) |
| 123apple | true (Incorrect result) |
| 123 | false |

---

### SOLUTION(S)

1. With `foreach` loop, stop iteration when detecting any character which is not a letter by `break`.

```
foreach (char letter in input)
{
    if (!char.IsLetter(letter))
    {
        isLetter = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

2. Using `.All()` from `System.Linq` namespace to check all characters must be a letter.

```
using System.Linq;

var isAllLetter = input.All(x => char.IsLetter(x));
```

3. Using `.Any()` from `System.Linq` namespace to check any characters is not a letter. This method is negated of Solution 2 and faster as it traces until detection of character is not a letter.

```
using System.Linq;

var isAllLetter = !input.Any(x => !char.IsLetter(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

const int MAX_LENGTH = 12;
const string SUFFIX = "ay";

private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string input = englishWordTextBox.Text.Trim();      
    if (input.Any() && input.Length <= MAX_LENGTH && input.All(char.IsLetter)) {
        pigLatinWordLabel.Text = input.Substring(1) + input[0] + SUFFIX;
    } else {
        // exeption stuff...
    }
}
```

Notes:

- `using System.Linq` imports some cool functios for iterables, such as strings
- `input.Any()` is a common way to check is an iterable has any element
- `input.All(char.IsLetter)` is a common way to check if all elements of an iterable attend to a condition. In this case, the function `char.IsLetter` will be applied to each element, and the final result will be True only if it is True for every element.
- `input.Substring(1)` is a shortcut to get the substring from position 1 to the end of the string. If you are c# 8 or grater, it could be just `input[1..]`